# AddonSK: how can window from require('sdk/window/utils').openDialog interact with main.js script?

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

I am writing a FF addon SDK plugin.

My main.js opens a popup window with :

```
var win = require('sdk/window/utils').openDialog({
        url:"http://www.example.com/index.html",
        features: Object.keys({
            resizable: true,
            scrollbars: true
        }).join(),
        name: "myWin"    
    });
```

I need the window to send data to the main.js (index.html is an external HTTP  classical html/JS page)

Answer (score 0):

1: add a [content script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts).
    using [pageMod](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod) or [tabs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs) API, inject a js file in to the http://www.example.com/index.html  page.

2: [sending message](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts#The_postMessage_API) from the content script, then add an message listener in the main.js

Comment: Thanks.. maybe a sample so it helps me ?

Comment: does not work :( looks like you cannot do that for openDialog windows

Answer (score 0):

In `main.js`:

```
var tab = win.tabs[0]; // as it is a pop-up window I assume it has only one tab

// attach content script to tab and access worker object  
var worker = tab.attach({
  contentScriptFile: self.data.url('popup_window_script.js'), //        script from file
  contentScript:     ''                                       // and/or script from string
});

// listen to worker / popup_window_script.js
worker.port.on('msg_from_popup_window_script_js', function ( msg ) {
  // your code
});

// speak to worker / popup_window_script.js
worker.port.emit('msg_from_main_js', 'your message');
```

In `popup_window_script.js`:

```
// listen (to main.js)
self.port.on('msg_from_main_js', function ( msg ) {
  // your code
});

// speak (to main.js)
self.port.emit('msg_from_popup_window_script_js', 'your message');
```